# Read .odf file with Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have found how one can write an *odf* file, but did not found any natively supported by Qt methods that allow to read. Is it possible at all? A small example will be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anything in Qt for this.

If you need to manipulate office documents from an application, you could look at using OpenOffice / LibreOffice in server mode controlled via the UNO bridge system. See the [`OpenOffice.org Developer's Guide`](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/OpenOffice.org_Developers_Guide) for details. Note: this is not trivial to get working correctly.

Comment: The issue is that I have to implement everything with Qt support. No external libs are allowed! Anyway will take a look on your link.

Answer (score 2):

While you are told you cannot use external libraries, this is something that various companies (Nokia and SKF for example) are successfully using the Callibra engine to do. They are based on Qt, so may perhaps be an option for you. www.calligra.org has a good few bits of information on it :)

Answer (score 1):

For as far as I'm aware, this functionality does not exist natively within Qt. There have been [requests in the past](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-9258?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel) and there has been mention of [ongoing work to read ODF](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2008/08/06/opendocument-format/) back in 2008, but nothing has been done with this so far to my knowledge.

Perhaps, based on the sources of QTextDocumentWriter for the ODF format, you could fashion your own solution. But I'm not sure how feasible this is. Looking at the sources of QTextOdfWriter, it seems doable, but just a lot of work.